# Use geom_segment to plot arrows for selected data points on an existing plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, upperbound

I have created a plot using ggplot2 package in R using the following data:

```
# Ind filt objs        flux  filt    objs err_flux#

01   4590 obj1 1005.448892  4590 errobj1   0.0401  
02   6220 obj1 1420.626789  6220 errobj1   0.0392  
03   7640 obj1 1855.581355  7640 errobj1   0.0432  
 *.......skipped lines...*    
20 21512 obj2  949.642188 21512 errobj2     0.1516    
21  2030 obj2    9.838299  2030 errobj2   **0.0000**  
22  2253 obj2   17.097003  2253 errobj2   **0.0000**  
23  2612 obj2   14.754347  2612 errobj2   **0.0000**  
24  3470 obj2   14.890868  3470 errobj2   **0.0000**
```

I am plotting **flux** vs **filt** with ggplot and then adding the y-error bars as defined in the **err_flux** column. 
I would like to draw arrows from the data points for which the **err_flux==0.**.

Here is my program so far:

```
g <- ggplot(finaldata[1:26, ], aes(x = filt, y = log10(flux), color = objs))
gf1 <- g + geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.8, pch = 15) + theme_bw()
gf <- gf1 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = log10(flux) + err_flux,
                              ymin = log10(flux) - err_flux),
                           size = 0.5, color = "darkgrey")
gff <-gf + xlab("wavelength") + ylim(0.3,4.5) +
          geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
gfinal <- gff + scale_color_hue(l = 10, c = 75)
```

The resulting plot is shown below :
[image]

Here is what I have tried to add arrows  (e.g. the 4 leftmost points for 'obj2' in the plot shown above, but it does not work:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(finaldata)) {
 if (finaldata$err_flux==0.){
   gfinal<-gfinal + geom_segment(x=finaldata$filt[i], y=finaldata$flux[i], xend=finaldata$filt[i], yend=finaldata$flux[i]-0.5,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.25,"cm")))
  }
 }
```

Moreover, if I apply 'geom_segment' to the subset of my actual data, it won't add to my existing plot (*gfinal*), due to different dimensions.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `annotate`, and don't use a `for` loop. Subset the data down to what you want annotated and use the `data` argument.

Comment: @Gregor : This is the first time I am trying to work with R for plotting, so this is what I tried :    `sub<-subset(finaldata[1:26,],finaldata$err_flux==0.)
 gfinal+annotate(sub,x=sub$filt,xend=sub$filt,y=sub$flux,yend=sub$flux-0.5,color="red")`

Comment: nevermind ! I needed to define this as follows: `annotate("segment",x=sub$filt,xend=sub$filt,y=log10(sub$flux),yend=log10(sub$flux)-0.5,color="red")`

Comment: If you'd like, answering your own question is encouraged when you work out the solution yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`Annotate` function helped me to draw downwards pointing arrows (upper bounds) from selected data points.

I replace the last part of my program, which used a for and a if loop with `geom_segment` to `annotate` as follows :

```
sub<-subset(finaldata[1:26,],finaldata[1:26,]$err_flux==0.)
gfinal+annotate("segment",x=sub$filt,xend=sub$filt,y=log10(sub$flux),yend=log10(sub$flux)-0.25,color="red",arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")))
```

which resulted in the following figure :[image: See 4 <code>red</code> arrows on 4 leftmost data points for "obj2"]